# Static code analysis tools for finding defects in unit tests?

Tags: .net, static-analysis

I'm looking for .NET static code analysis tools that can detect things like unit tests without an assert, too many asserts in one test, and other anomalies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [Typemock Test Lint](http://site.typemock.com/test-lint).

Although it's produced by Typemock, it's not particularly tied to their commercial Isolator product. As an example, it analyzes my [xUnit.net](http://xunit.codeplex.com/) tests that use [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/).

It's free, but only available for Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for finding this!

Comment: Anyone know of a similar application for Java?